# Unable to remove a directory in git

Tags: git

I have an empty git directory I'd like to remove, however

`"git rm -r NameOfDirectory"` is returning `"operation not permitted"`.

In addition, if I move a new file into this directory then do git status, git does not list it as a new untracked file, but it does if I move the file into another directory, so there's something strange about it.

How I can get rid of this directory?

`git rm -r -f` doesn't solve it.

Comment: You don't have permission to remove the directory. Either use `sudo` or get someone who has the necessary permissions to remove the directory for you.

Comment: Thank. But it was me who added that directory in the first place, how could I suddenly not have permission for this particular directory?

Comment: Because you're a different user? Again: use `sudo` or ask someone with the correct permissions.

Comment: Could you post the result of a `ls -l` on the parent directory?

Comment: I've resolved it, there as a hidden OS X .DS_Store file in the directory, when I deleted that things were ok. Thanks for every bodies answers, I've learned a few new things about Git due to your replies.

Answer (score 2):

It's a permission issue.

try

`sudo git rm -r NameOfDirectory` with the root password

You may try to remove the directory without using the git command but the `rm` command directly.

`rm -r NameOfDirectory` or `sudo rm -r NameOfDirectory`

Comment: I'm using the terminal in OS X, and when it prompts me to enter the password the terminal isn't accepting any input from the keyboard, so I'm unable to actually enter the password.

Comment: What Jack said. It just doesn't show you what you're inputting, since it's *sensitive information*.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't track empty directories. If you have an empty directory in your working tree you should simply removed it with `rmdir`. There is no need to involve Git.